# serial command to debian/armbian to shutdown system

Tags: python, arduino, debian, shutdown, orange-pi

since my other take on this did not yield any results, I did the following:
I have an Orange Pi PC which I want to shutdown once the Arduino Lenoardo connected to it via USB gets an input on Pin 2 via a button.

This whole communication should act out via serial, as keyboard inputs did not work well.

My Pi is running RetrOrangePi, a clone of RetroPie for the Orange Pi Hardware.
Now, if I want it to shutdown, I do not want to use the menu, but a button instead, mounted on the Hardware Case.

When this button (connected to Pin 2 on the Arduino) is pressed, it sends a serial command (byebyepi) to the Orange Pi, which runs a python daemon that listens for this exact line to send the shutdown command.

Nearly everything works well.
The Arduino sends the serial signal when pin 2 is grounded,
checked on windows with the serial Monitor.
The init.d service is running.
Only the python script had a problem, when I ran it manually,
since a module (serial) was missing.
I installed pip and then with pip i installed the "pyserial" module.
Which got rid of the error that this module was missing.

Now, when I manually run the python script, the arduino is listening,
but when I ground Pin 2, nothing happens. The Arduino lights up the led,
so signal it sent the shutdown command, but the Pi is not shutting down
and I have no idea why. I also did chmod 755 on my init.d/byebyepi.

Can anyone here help me with that? Thank you kindly!

**The sketch for my arduino is this:**

```
#define abutton 2
//Pin 2 is now called abutton

void setup() {
  pinMode(abutton,INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (!digitalRead(abutton)){Serial.println("byebyepi");
//send byebyepi via serial when abutton is used
  delay(5000);
//wait for 5 seconds
  }
}
```

**My python daemon uses this:**

```
import serial
import os

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1 :
   line = ser.readline()
   if line == 'byebyepi':
      os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
```

**And the /etc/init.d/ script is this:**

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/byebyepi
#

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting byebyepi.py"
    # run application you want to start
    python /home/pi/shutdown/byebyepi.py &
    ;;
  stop)
    # kill application you want to stop
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /home/pi/shutdown/byebyepi.py {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: You could maybe add some more related tags to your question (e.g. `arduino`, `orange-pi`, etc) and get it some more attention

Comment: @downshift done, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be a good idea to send a blank line before sending the command:

```
if (!digitalRead(abutton)){
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("byebyepi");
}
```

Otherwise characters generated by electrical noise might end up in the beginning of the string. A new line character should get the python script to go once around in the reading loop, and then be ready to receive a clear string.

Otherwise you could add some print output to the Python script, that just says that it is about to reboot. Just so you can confirm that the Python script receives the command ok.

One more thing is that when running in an init.d script, your environment variables will not be the same as when you are logged in. For example the PATH and PYTHONPATH can be different. So it might be a good idea to use the full path to `shutdown` in the python script. It is this line:

```
os.system("sudo FULLPATHHERE/shutdown -h now")
```

You'll have to find out what it is on your system. Maybe you should remove the sudo also for the init.d script.